# Corona: Can't get instance to "jump" on screen touch

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Trying to get a sprite (instance1) to jump on touch, but it won't work.

Here is my code:

```
physics.addBody( instance1, { density=1.0, friction=0.3, bounce=0.3} )
local function jump( event )
  if(event.numTaps == 2) then

    instance1:applyForce( 350, -2000, instance1.x, instance1.y )
  end
end

instance1:addEventListener("tap", jump)
```

I will add, that if I do this, the sprite instance will jump once, but never again:

```
local function jump( event )
  if(event.numTaps == 2) then
    physics.addBody( instance1, { density=1.0, friction=0.3, bounce=0.3} )
    instance1:applyForce( 350, -2000, instance1.x, instance1.y )
  end
end

instance1:addEventListener("tap", jump)
```

Instance info:

```
local sheet1 = sprite.newSpriteSheet( "character.png", 75, 105 )

local spriteSet1 = sprite.newSpriteSet(sheet1, 1, 16)

sprite.add( spriteSet1, "character", 1, 12, 700, 1 ) -- play 12 frames every 700 ms

local instance1 = sprite.newSprite( spriteSet1 )

instance1.x = display.contentWidth/2
instance1.y = 240
```

Comment: can we see more code about `instance1`? I cant reproduce your error when i assume `instance1` as a rectangle.

Comment: @cctan: added the intance1 info.

Answer (score 0):

still cant reproduce your error,
i answered your question to paste the code i tested:

```
--main.lua
local sprite=require("sprite")
local physics=require("physics")

local sheet1 = sprite.newSpriteSheet( "character.png", 75, 105 )

local spriteSet1 = sprite.newSpriteSet(sheet1, 1, 16)

sprite.add( spriteSet1, "character", 1, 12, 700, 1 ) -- play 12 frames every 700 ms

local instance1 = sprite.newSprite( spriteSet1 )

instance1.x = display.contentWidth/2
instance1.y = 240

physics.start()
physics.setGravity(0,1)
physics.addBody( instance1, { density=1.0, friction=0.3, bounce=0.3} )
local function jump( event )
  if(event.numTaps == 2) then

    instance1:applyForce( 35, -200, instance1.x, instance1.y )
  end
end

instance1:addEventListener("tap", jump)
```